# How to figure out if the string key exists in a map?

Tags: c++, c++11

Considering a simple `std::map<std::string*,std::string*>`, I want to check if the value of a string pointer exists in the map or not.
I have tried this, but the compiler looks for the pointer itself in the map while I want to check the pointed (actual) values.

```
int main() {
    map<string*,string*> c;
    std::string a("dude");
    std::string* b=new string("dude");
    std::string* ap;
    c.insert(std::make_pair<string*,string*>(&a,&a));
    for( map<string*, string*>::iterator ii=c.begin(); ii!=c.end(); ++ii){
        ap=(*ii).first;
        if(ap->compare(*b)){
            cout<<"Yeah, dude has been found\n";
        }
    }
    if(c.find(b)==c.end()){
        cout<<"No dude!\n";//wrong!
    }
    if(c.count(b)==0){//how to find out if there is dude string?
        cout<<"No dude dude!\n";//wrong!
    }else{
        cout<<"Yeah, dude has been found\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Generally, I have two string pointers and I want to compare the strings. How would I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just using strings instead of pointers?

Comment: strings may be huge, so I like to pass data by pointer rather value. @chris

Comment: Especially with C++11, that shouldn't be a problem. Have you profiled and found it to be a problem?

Comment: @parsaporahmad - Right now, your program is a toy program.  As soon as you expand on it, you will quickly see that storing pointers as keys is a very bad idea.

Comment: Yes, the number and size of each string is big, also keys are passed to many functions which kills the memory by passing by value. @chris

Comment: @parsaporahmad - Have you not heard of passing by reference?  Even with the toy program you posted, you failed to deallocate the memory.  Now multiply that little mistake with many functions, many calls, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie dear, what is your suggestion? changing the string* to string will eat up the notable amount of the memory and I'm not feel good about this. what should I do buddy?

Comment: @parsaporahmad You are "eating up memory" whether or not the string is in the map.  The string must exist somewhere, right?

Comment: In C++ there is rarely any need for pointers, avoid them as far as possible. And always *always* ***benchmark!***

Comment: Also, if your strings are so big (I hope you talk about at least several tens kilobytes), then maybe `std::map` is not the right data-structure for you. You might also want to learn [what the XY problem is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (in short: ask about a solution for your *actual* problem, not for us to help fix your existing solution to an (for us) unknown problem).

Comment: @parsaporahmad - If your goal is to look up a name as a key, then store the name (i.e. std::string) as a key, *not a pointer*.  I can easily break that program by changing the data that the pointer points to, and then you're searching for a name that no longer exists, even though you believe it exists.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you so much dear, your suggestion helped me too much, I'm going to change the structure and switch to references, and will be back if I get some issues. thanks buddy :D.

Comment: @parsaporahmad If you really want to use pointers use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` after you decide who has ownership of those `string` pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really use pointers as keys, unless you actually want the *pointer* to be the key and not what it points to.

The pointer `&a` and the pointer `b` are different, that's why you don't find the key.

Use plain (non-pointer) `std::string` as the key instead, and it should work much better.

Comment: @Deduplicator Of course, but that's a lot of extra work when when using non-pointers will work "out of the box".

Comment: `std::string` ay work out of the box, but it means copying that string. Your answer atm. does not answer that point imho.

Comment: @Deduplicator If the OP is in such a memory-constrained environment that the OP don't want to use `std::string` and copying, then the OP should probably not be using dynamic memory allocations or maybe even not C++. For the OP: ***Benchmark!*** Always try the "naive" solution before dismissing it, premature optimizations and all that.

Comment: Thank you buddy, this solves the problem, and I would pass the value by reference or pointer to the next stack element. thank you dear.

Answer (score 2):

If after careful measurement and consideration you are still sure you cannot accept duplicating those `std::string`s and can guarantee the `string`s will stay around as long as the map, consider the following approaches. Refrain from using them just because.

The simplest approach is just using a `std::reference_wrapper<T>`. It has the same semantics as a raw pointer, except that comparison/hash and such are performed on the referenced object.
Chnossos just mentioned that useful standard library member.

Leaving my older answers after this point, because they allow more customisation.

Add your own `struct wrapped_pointer{std::string* x}` and specialise the comparator `std::less` to consider the pointed to string.

Just about the same can be achieved providing an explicit argument for the third template argument of `std::map`.

Comment: Still trying to figure out what would happen with a key type of `string&`. That ight be interesting and perhaps even relevant here.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: What would you think appropriate behaviour if you might allow it for them? Actually using a pointer but handling it everywhere but for copying just like the pointed to value? Because I think that would be a natural and useful interpretation.

Comment: If, after careful measurements have been made to conclude that using plain `std::string` is not acceptable, then your solution but using [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) ***everywhere*** might be a viable solution. However, one mistake by the OP will cause the application to crash and burn.

Comment: @Joachim: Yes, not using the simplest implementation in the name of efficiency always has its own price-tag, which might be prohibitive.

Comment: Isn't `std::reference_wrapper<std::string>` acceptable in this case ?

Comment: @Chnossos: That's perfect, adding that.

Comment: Perfect, perfect `std::reference_wrapper<std::string>` helped too much, thanks dude. @Chnossos

Comment: Glad it helped. In modern C++, there is almost always a solution to avoid pointers !

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want to if you provide a custom function/functor to compare two `string*`s.

Here's a version that works as you are thinking:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Define a functor class to compare two string* objects.
struct string_less
{
   bool operator()(string* lhs, string* rhs) const
   {
      return (lhs->compare(*rhs) < 0);
   }
};

int main() {

    // Use string_less while constructing the map.
    map<string*,string*, string_less> c;
    std::string a("dude");
    std::string* b=new string("dude");
    std::string* ap;
    c.insert(std::make_pair<string*,string*>(&a,&a));
    for( map<string*, string*, string_less>::iterator ii=c.begin(); ii!=c.end(); ++ii){
        ap=(*ii).first;

        // This was another line that needed to be fixed.
        if(ap->compare(*b) == 0 ){
            cout<<"Yeah, dude has been found\n";
        }
    }
    if(c.find(b)==c.end()){
        cout<<"No dude!\n";//wrong!
    }
    if(c.count(b)==0){//how to find out if there is dude string?
        cout<<"No dude dude!\n";//wrong!
    }else{
        cout<<"Yeah, dude has been found\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of running the program on my machine:

```
Yeah, dude has been found
Yeah, dude has been found
```

Comment: Why not just use a lambda, or at least a function?

Comment: @Deduplicator, using a functor is easier than a function when creating the map. If `string_less` were to be a function, the syntax for constructing `c` would be `map<string*,string*, bool (*)(string*, string*)> c(string_less);`.

Comment: @RSahu, Or, more simply, `decltype(string_less)`.